# How to install requirements.txt

Tags: python, python-3.x, raspberry-pi3

new to programming here. I was trying to follow a programming project i found online here:

[How to Make a Raspberry Pi Smart Mirror - YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fkVBAcvbrjU)[^]

However, when I tried to install requirements.txt with - sudo pip3 install -r requirements.txt . I get this thrown back at me :

`Requirement already satisfied: requests in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 1))
Collecting feedparser (from -r requirements.txt (line 2))
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/urllib3-1.19.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 594, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked)
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/urllib3-1.19.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 391, in _make_request
    six.raise_from(e, None)
  File "&lt;string&gt;", line 2, in raise_from
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/urllib3-1.19.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 387, in _make_request
    httplib_response = conn.getresponse()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 1198, in getresponse
    response.begin()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 297, in begin
    version, status, reason = self._read_status()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 266, in _read_status
    raise RemoteDisconnected("Remote end closed connection without"
http.client.RemoteDisconnected: Remote end closed connection without response

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 353, in run
    wb.build(autobuilding=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 749, in build
    self.requirement_set.prepare_files(self.finder)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 380, in prepare_files
    ignore_dependencies=self.ignore_dependencies))
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 620, in _prepare_file
    session=self.session, hashes=hashes)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/download.py", line 821, in unpack_url
    hashes=hashes
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/download.py", line 659, in unpack_http_url
    hashes)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/download.py", line 853, in _download_http_url
    stream=True,
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/requests-2.12.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl/requests/sessions.py", line 501, in get
    return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/download.py", line 386, in request
    return super(PipSession, self).request(method, url, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/requests-2.12.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl/requests/sessions.py", line 488, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/requests-2.12.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl/requests/sessions.py", line 609, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/CacheControl-0.11.7-py2.py3-none-any.whl/cachecontrol/adapter.py", line 47, in send
    resp = super(CacheControlAdapter, self).send(request, **kw)
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/requests-2.12.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl/requests/adapters.py", line 423, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/urllib3-1.19.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 643, in urlopen
    _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/urllib3-1.19.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 315, in increment
    total -= 1
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -=: 'Retry' and 'int'`

For further clarification, I am running this program on my raspberry pi and I have both python 2.7 and 3 installed. Could having both python 2.7 and 3 be the problem?

Any help with this would be extremely great. 
So sorry if I have not asked a well documented question.

Thanks!

Comment: Looks like the main error is a network error. Did you lose internet when it was running?

Comment: Last I check, my raspberry pi was still connected to the internet. Is there any other solution available?

Comment: @Matthew Have you confirmed that it isn’t actually network-related?

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply! 

How do I check if it's a network related issue? Do I just see if I can connect to the internet through a chrome browser?